# Slicer not populating on different worksheet than table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a a few sheets, each with their own Pivot Tables ad graphs. On my dashboard I have imported in all of the graphs, and I want to place a slicer on this worksheet that is connected to one of the Pivot Tables on a previous table. And then after that I plan to report connections to the remaining Pivot Tables/Graphs. Stepping into the code shows that it reads just fine, but nothing appears on the worksheet, and no slicer is generated for me to use.

Gone through and Recorded Macro, selected desired graph, inserted slicer, and then copied that code to my macro, where it then preceded to do nothing. The code below is what Recorded Macro generated. The graph "Totals graph" is located on worksheet Dashboard, pivot table "total sales each customer" is located on worksheet "total sales", and the slicer "ship quantity" is trying to be placed on worksheet Dashboard.

I have also confirmed that I have all of the pivot tables in the workbook referencing a single pivot cache.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Totals Graph").Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add2(ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "Total Sales Each Customer"), "ShipQuantity").Slicers.Add ActiveSheet, , "ShipQuantity 1", "ShipQuantity", _
         243.75, 765, 144, 198.75

 ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_ShipQuantity1").PivotTables.AddPivotTable 
        ( ActiveSheet.PivotTables("GrossMarg$"))
```

Again, output right now is nothing. Would enjoying seeing the slicer appear.

Comment: You need to change `ActiveSheet` to the actual worksheet you expect the data/info to be on/from.

Comment: @BruceWayne the Batman, that worked perfectly! Thanks for your help!

For anyone wondering, In the first block of code I changed the first "ActiveSheet" to "Sheets("total sales")" and the "ActiveSheet" in Slicers.Add changed to "Sheets("Dashboard")"